# ngShow not working with UI-Router StickyStates

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

We are using AngularJS 1.7.x with UI-Router v5 and sticky states. The application is in a CodePen Project: https://codepen.io/DavidNJ/project/editor/XgLYyz

Basically, Sticky States keeps the state active just as a parent state is kept active. To only show one, the others need to be hidden.

UI-Router recommends using ng-show. To make this easier to see, the application has encapsulated `$state.includes(<state name>)` in a function that writes a log message. It shows that `true` is being returned to `ng-show`

```
    <div ui-view="v1" ng-show="ac.inState('view1')"></div>
    <div ui-view="v2" ng-show="ac.inState('view2')"></div>
```

and

```
    vm.inState = (state)=>{
        console.log("checking " +state +": "+$state.includes(state));
        $state.includes(state);
    };
```

`ng-show` puts the `ng-hide` class in the tag until `ng-show` is `true`. However, even though the function returns `true` the class is never changed to `ng-show`

This is probably something simple but has totally stumped us.

Thanks,

David

Comment: The `ui-view` directive creates a child scope. Could the `ac.inState` function be on child scope and not of the parent scope that `ng-show` uses?

Comment: Looking at elements in Chrome, both the view1 and view2 sticky states are created under the ui-view. We are still baffled.